# How to display hyphens as □ in taskpaper files?

Tags: conceal

I’m using [taskpaper.vim](https://github.com/davidoc/taskpaper.vim) to work with projects and tasks and would like to display the hyphen that starts a tasks as the □ (unicode white square). I don't want to actually replace the character in the text, but simply display it this way.

Answer (score 3):

The conceal feature will let you do this. Following the example [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/adding-conceal-to-already-existing-syntax-highlighting), I came up with this solution.

```
:call matchadd('Conceal', '^-', 10, -1, {'conceal': '□'})
:set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

Note that the pattern is a hyphen in column 1. If you want to allow whitespace before the hyphen, change the pattern to `'^\s*\zs-'`.